# Filter filter criteria and then apply in countif statement in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table of filter criteria like this:

```
+----------+----------+------+------+------+
| Category | SpecName | Spec | Pass | Fail |
+----------+----------+------+------+------+
| A        | S1       |    3 |      |      |
| A        | S2       |    4 |      |      |
| B        | S1       |    5 |      |      |
| C        | S1       |    2 |      |      |
+----------+----------+------+------+------+
```

I have a table I want to apply the filter criteria to like this:

```
+----------+----+----+
| Category | S1 | S2 |
+----------+----+----+
| A        |  5 |  3 |
| B        |  4 |    |
| A        |  5 |  5 |
| C        |  2 |    |
| A        |  2 |  6 |
+----------+----+----+
```

I want to fill the Pass and Fail columns in the filter criteria table with a count of items in second table with values >= the corresponding spec, like so.

```
+----------+----------+------+------+------+
| Category | SpecName | Spec | Pass | Fail |
+----------+----------+------+------+------+
| A        | S1       |    3 |    1 |    2 |
| A        | S2       |    4 |    1 |    2 |
| B        | S1       |    5 |    0 |    1 |
| C        | S1       |    2 |    1 |    0 |
+----------+----------+------+------+------+
```

Here are steps for how I might do it in a scripting language:

1. Filter first table to get all spec filter criteria for the Category on that row, as follows for the first row.

```
+----------+----------+------+
| Category | SpecName | Spec |
+----------+----------+------+
| A        | S1       |    3 |
| A        | S2       |    4 |
+----------+----------+------+
```

2. Copy table 2 to a variable **iTable**

```
+----------+----+----+
| Category | S1 | S2 |
+----------+----+----+
| A        |  5 |  3 |
| B        |  4 |    |
| A        |  5 |  5 |
| C        |  2 |    |
| A        |  2 |  6 |
+----------+----+----+
```

3. For each spec name:
      Find column in iTable with spec name
      Filter spec name column in **iTable** by spec
4. After all filters applied, we would have:

```
+----------+----+----+
| Category | S1 | S2 |
+----------+----+----+
| A        |  5 |  5 |
+----------+----+----+
```

5. Then just count the rows in **iTable** and assign to the cell in **Pass** column of the criteria table

Is this possible with Excel formulas?

If not, does anyone know how to do it with VBA?

Comment: so in your results table, every entry withe the same category name would wind up having the same pass and fail counts?  Subsequent entries of the same category name are just additional criteria that also have to be met for a pass?  ie you want a count of catergory A that has S1 >= 3 and S2>= 4?

Comment: is the maximum occurance of a category 2?  Ie there is aonly S1 and S2?  Will that table always be sorted so that A S2 is on the line below A S1?  Can the layout of your first table be modified slightly?

Comment: That is correct @ForwardEd. I want the count of all entries in **iTable** that match all the criteria. for Category A that would be S1 >= 3 and S2>= 4.

Comment: The layout can be modified, but the categories are unkown. For the sake of this example, I have 2. In reality I have 6, but this is a variable and I cannot make this assumption. I also cannot guarantee order, because the client wants the freedom to sort this however he desires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at an alternative layout for you spec criteria.  Expand you columns to suit your need.

[image: Alt Table 1 Layout]

With each spec criteria being its own column life gets really easy.  You just need to adjust your formula to match the number of criteria you have.

Based on the table at the end for layout, place the following formula in D3 and copy down as required.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($G$2:$G$6=A3)*($H$2:$H$6>=B3)*($I$2:$I$6>=C3))
```

That will give you a count of passing all criteria.  Its also a function that performs array like calcs.  It could be repeated in the next column but in order to reduce dependency on array calculation and potentially speed things up depending on the amount of data to check, place the following in the top of the fail column and copy down as required:

```
=COUNTIF($G$2:$G$6,A3)-D3
```

Basically it subtracts the passes from the total count.  This assumes you can only have PASS and FAIL as options.

[image: POC]

Comment: This is beautiful, but I need it to work for a variable number of filters. Category A may have 6 filters and category B may share 2 filters with A and then have another of its own. Once I make this spreadsheet I will give it away and not touch it again, so any dragging of formulas that might need to be done for maintenance is not an option for me. Is there a way to take exactly what you have done such an amazing job with and make it accept variable filters?

Comment: Create the 10 columns, if the criteria are not use it wont matter. as long as it also remains blank in the second table.  However this may still not be an option for you.  It can be done via VBA but VBA is not my strong suit.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because it was what I ended up using. It isn't perfect, but given that the filters won't change that much it will work. I just didn't want to have to do maintenance on this thing later, but ...